# How to create tables in a linked table using OPENQUERY?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I have several tables that I would like to create in a linked server using `OPENQUERY`.

Basically, I have a query which fills a table (TableA) that is run on the linked server (ServerB). I am working on a way to run this query from a different server (ServerA) that has the other (ServerB) as a linked server.

So I have *ServerA* where I am attempting to run this query, but the query ends up being way too long so I've had to shorten it and break it out into about 8 different queries. For this, to work I need to put the results from each of the broken out queries into tables (Table1, Table2, etc.). When finished I will delete the tables as they will only be needed when this query is run from *ServerA*.

I've looked around the internet trying to find a way that works I've tried:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @LinkedServerName nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @LinkedDbName nvarchar(100)
SET @LinkedServerName = 'SQLINFWWDVP07'
SET @LinkedDbName = 'Varasset'
SET @table = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.WOResults(id INT NULL);';
SET @sql = N'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(@LinkedServerName) + N'.' 
  + QUOTENAME(@LinkedDbName) + N'.sys.sp_executesql @table;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@table NVARCHAR(MAX)', @table;
```

Which gives me the error:

> Server 'SQLINFWWDVP07' is not configured for RPC.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SQLINFWWDVP07,'
exec (''create table [ext].[WOResults]([Id] uniqueidentifier,[AltWorkOrderId] nvarchar(50),[WORK ORDER STATUS] nvarchar(30),[DESCRIPTION] nvarchar(200),
    [STATE] uniqueidentifier,[PROJ APVL] nvarchar(30),[EST COMP] nvarchar(30),[ACT COMP] nvarchar(30),[cd_M6OrderNo] nvarchar(50),[CDD Date] nvarchar(30),
    [FinancialProject] uniqueidentifier,[AssignedLocation] uniqueidentifier,[PROJ TYPE] uniqueidentifier,[CLASS OF PLANT] uniqueidentifier,
    [Justification Code] uniqueidentifier,[CLOSING NOTES] nvarchar(MAX),[READY FOR SERVICE EST] nvarchar(30),[READY FOR SERVICE ACT] nvarchar(30),
    [EOJ] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT PICK] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT COMP] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT STATUS] nvarchar(100),[FullyReceivedDate] nvarchar(30),
    [% MTL RECEIVED] decimal(18,5),[ASSIGNED USER] nvarchar(200),[WORK ORDER NOTES] nvarchar(MAX));'') ')
```

Which gives me the error:

> Cannot process the object " *(Then the whole of the query)* The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SQLINFWWDVP07" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

So I would then try this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SQLINFWWDVP07,'
exec (''create table [ext].[WOResults]([Id] uniqueidentifier,[AltWorkOrderId] nvarchar(50),[WORK ORDER STATUS] nvarchar(30),[DESCRIPTION] nvarchar(200),
    [STATE] uniqueidentifier,[PROJ APVL] nvarchar(30),[EST COMP] nvarchar(30),[ACT COMP] nvarchar(30),[cd_M6OrderNo] nvarchar(50),[CDD Date] nvarchar(30),
    [FinancialProject] uniqueidentifier,[AssignedLocation] uniqueidentifier,[PROJ TYPE] uniqueidentifier,[CLASS OF PLANT] uniqueidentifier,
    [Justification Code] uniqueidentifier,[CLOSING NOTES] nvarchar(MAX),[READY FOR SERVICE EST] nvarchar(30),[READY FOR SERVICE ACT] nvarchar(30),
    [EOJ] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT PICK] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT COMP] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT STATUS] nvarchar(100),[FullyReceivedDate] nvarchar(30),
    [% MTL RECEIVED] decimal(18,5),[ASSIGNED USER] nvarchar(200),[WORK ORDER NOTES] nvarchar(MAX));'') 
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''ext'' AND TABLE_NAME = ''WOResults'') 
BEGIN select ''Table Created'' END')
```

Which gives me no errors, but also does not create the table in the linked server (ServerB).

I've also tried both ways but without the `exec` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SQLINFWWDVP07,'
create table [ext].[WOResults]([Id] uniqueidentifier,[AltWorkOrderId] nvarchar(50),[WORK ORDER STATUS] nvarchar(30),[DESCRIPTION] nvarchar(200),
    [STATE] uniqueidentifier,[PROJ APVL] nvarchar(30),[EST COMP] nvarchar(30),[ACT COMP] nvarchar(30),[cd_M6OrderNo] nvarchar(50),[CDD Date] nvarchar(30),
    [FinancialProject] uniqueidentifier,[AssignedLocation] uniqueidentifier,[PROJ TYPE] uniqueidentifier,[CLASS OF PLANT] uniqueidentifier,
    [Justification Code] uniqueidentifier,[CLOSING NOTES] nvarchar(MAX),[READY FOR SERVICE EST] nvarchar(30),[READY FOR SERVICE ACT] nvarchar(30),
    [EOJ] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT PICK] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT COMP] nvarchar(30),[AUDIT STATUS] nvarchar(100),[FullyReceivedDate] nvarchar(30),
    [% MTL RECEIVED] decimal(18,5),[ASSIGNED USER] nvarchar(200),[WORK ORDER NOTES] nvarchar(MAX))
IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''ext'' AND TABLE_NAME = ''WOResults'') 
BEGIN select ''Table Created'' END')
```

And get the same results.

Is there a way to create a table in a linked server using `OPENQUERY`?

I have also tried using `select * into` to create the table but would get the same results as the last two examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use EXEC ... AT

```
EXEC ('create table tempdb.dbo.t(id int)') At [192.1.1.2]
```

For RPC error. you can enable RPC OUT

[image]

Comment: I just tried that, though I had to use the Server Name since the IP just said that it cannot find that in the linked server list. I get the same error message as in my first example above: `Server 'SQLINFWWDVP07' is not configured for RPC.`

Comment: @Mike, For RPC error, you only need enable the RPC OUT, otherwise you cannot write remote server